# Page infinite time reload issue

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth

I am using google `OAuth` using JavaScript and PHP when  users successfully login page is reloading infinite time.

```
<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) { 

    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile(); 
    var id= profile.getId(); 
    var name=profile.getName(); 
    var image=profile.getImageUrl(); 
    var email=profile.getEmail();
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

    $.ajax({
     url:'google-login',
     method:'post',
     data:{name,image,email,id,id_token},
     }).done(function() {
      window.location.reload();
     });

  }

<script>
```

I want when user successfully register/login with google OAuth API page is reloaded one time.

Comment: you can use setTimeOut !

Comment: I have tired, but not find any solution

Comment: Can you please do this.

$.ajax(url:'google-login', method:'post', data:{name, image, email, id, id_token}, function(data){
    if (data.success == true)
        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 5000);
    })
)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'google-login',
    method:'post',
    data:{name, image, email, id, id_token},
    success: function(data) {
       if (data.success == true) 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
             window.location.reload(); 
             }, 5000);
            }               
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but not any result, Please help me to solve this one

Comment: could you please confirm whether your Ajax call occurs once or many time and after the Ajax call success window reload should call after 5 milliseconds !